# how to getAuth token and send email in background?

Tags: android, email

I have used JavaMail-android libraries to send mail in background .In order to free user from username and password I decided to use Auth token generated when adding an account /configuring account in android phone .So can i get the token and how could i use the token to send mail in background as a did using smtp (javamail-android) libraries .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi its so simple and easy call your email sending class through [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) it will work automatically email will send on particular time.

Here i have posted sample code:
you should write code in service as `GMailSender sender = new GMailSender(send_id,send_pass,imgpath);`
its for sending email through your gmail id only.

and now GmailSender.java as follows:

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator
```

{

```
private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
private String user;   
private String password;   
private Session session;   
private String path_img;  

static {   
    // AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.1");
    Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());   
}  

public GMailSender(String user, String password,String path) 
{  
    path_img = path;
    // AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.2");
    this.user = user;   
    this.password = password;   

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");


    //AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.3");
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
    //AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.4");
}   





protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
}   

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
    try{

    //   AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.5");
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session); 
   // AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.6");
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/html"));   
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
    //AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.7");
    message.setSubject(subject);   

    message.setDataHandler(handler);  

    MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
    String htmlText=null;

    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    htmlText = body+ "";

    messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");



    MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource(path_img) {
        @Override
        public String getContentType() {
            return "image/jpg";
        }
    };
    attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource));
    attachmentPart.setFileName("image.jpg");

    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
   multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);

    message.setContent(multipart);

    //AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.8");
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
    {
        //AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.9");
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
        Transport.send(message); 
      //  AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step2.1");
    }
    else 
    {
        //AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step2.2");
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));  
        Transport.send(message); 
    //AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step2.3");
    }
   // Transport.send(message); 
   // AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step2.4");
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
      }





}   

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
    private byte[] data;   
    private String type;   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
    }   

    public void setType(String type) {   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public String getContentType() {   
        if (type == null)   
            return "application/octet-stream";   
        else  
            return type;   
    }   

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
    }   

    public String getName() {   
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
    }   

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
    }   
}
```

try this sample and try for all email ids. and make sure that you have import all libraries needed..

Comment: thanks .i need to authenticate using the authtoken generated when user adds account to account manager and use this account to pass authentication and send email via gmail in background