# How to receive the email with attachment?

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

How to use javaMail API in android for receiving mail with attachment.
Pls give me some code or steps which is use in Android.

Comment: please do some google and R&D before posting your Question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Do some R&D before posting.what you tried before posting this Question?
check this [how to getAuth token and send email in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108320/how-to-getauth-token-and-send-email-in-background/9108387#9108387)
For attachment you can use this. i have given some sample to attach image from your gallery.

```
 MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource(path_img) {
        @Override
        public String getContentType() {
            return "image/jpg";
        }
    };
    attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource));
    attachmentPart.setFileName("image.jpg");

    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
   multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);

    message.setContent(multipart);
```

Comment: Dear is this really an answer? Instead it should be a comment as per the SO rule.

Comment: @PareshMayani check updated ans.  and as i have given ans. to related Question then is it necessary to post whole ans. again here?

Comment: if answer is already exists, then you just need to provide an answer link on question as a comment, not as a Redundant answer.